# Not able to install erlang on ubuntu 22.04

Tags: apt, dependencies

```
sudo apt install erlang
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 erlang : Depends: erlang-appmon
          Depends: erlang-crypto
          Depends: erlang-inets
          Depends: erlang-ssl
 erlang-common-test : Depends: erlang-crypto (= 1:24.3.3-1)
                      Depends: erlang-inets (= 1:24.3.3-1)
 erlang-diameter : Depends: erlang-ssl (= 1:24.3.3-1)
 erlang-edoc : Depends: erlang-inets (= 1:24.3.3-1)
 erlang-eldap : Depends: erlang-ssl (= 1:24.3.3-1)
 erlang-observer : Depends: erlang-appmon (= 1:24.3.3-1)
                   Depends: erlang-inets (= 1:24.3.3-1)
 erlang-percept : Depends: erlang-inets (= 1:24.3.3-1)
 erlang-public-key : Depends: erlang-crypto (= 1:24.3.3-1)
 erlang-snmp : Depends: erlang-crypto (= 1:24.3.3-1)
 erlang-ssh : Depends: erlang-crypto (= 1:24.3.3-1)
 erlang-tools : Depends: erlang-inets (= 1:24.3.3-1)
```

Comment: Simply posting logvomit without reading the error messages is unforgivably lazy.

Comment: Did you do an `apt update` before the `apt install`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa)